# I want to use LSTM to predict the arrival time of navires (boats/vessels)

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, python, lstm

The data that I have contain the time of arrival of the vessel (TA) and also the time spent to berth (ETB) for every vessel during the last year.

I want to predict the ETB using LSTM in a deep hybrid model (I'm using different models outputs as an input for other models), but I'm still trying to fully understand if the use of LSTM or any other time series model is the right choice to make, as I think that there is a kinda of time dependency between ETB and the time of the year (different weather conditions)

Comment: This is very little to build on. Can you tel us more (sample size?), show some plots (edit the post).  Maybe start with some simpler models to see what is possible ...